# Zoho crm api v2 for php

Tags: php, crm, zoho

I am trying to connect with Zoho CRM using PHP. I followed [PHP SDK](https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk) for Zoho CRM and installed the package.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use zcrmsdk\crm\setup\restclient\ZCRMRestClient;
use zcrmsdk\oauth\ZohoOAuth;



$configuration =array("client_id"=>"clientid","client_secret"=>"clientsecret","redirect_uri"=>"redirecturl","currentUserEmail"=>"useremail");

$a = ZCRMRestClient::initialize($configuration);

$oAuthClient = ZohoOAuth::getClientInstance();
$refreshToken = "refreshtoken";
$userIdentifier = "emailid";
$oAuthTokens = $oAuthClient->generateAccessTokenFromRefreshToken($refreshToken,$userIdentifier);




$result = ZCRMRestClient::getModule("Contacts");
print_r($result);
exit;
?>
```

**error I am getting:**

```
Not able to get access token from refresh token, invalid client_id.
```

But I am using correct credentials to connect Zoho API.

Comment: have you checked it by passing one more parameter `prompt=consent` ?

Answer (score 1):

Spent a day on this myself when I set it up.

Make sure that you are using the same domain for the api and the oauth client app.

They have 2 domains:

- https://accounts.zoho.com
- https://accounts.zoho.eu

If you created the oauth clinet app on one, use the same one for the api endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Further to this, if you are using accounts_url=https://accounts.zoho.eu in the oauth_configuration.properties file, then you should also set apiBaseUrl=www.zohoapis.eu in the configuration.properties file.

Given the parameters are read from these two properties files, I don't think you need that configuration array.